# How do I compare python functions in terms of performance?

Tags: python, performance, function, compare

I have written 2 functions doing the exact same thing, but I don't know which one is faster and better. How do I compare these 2 functions to see which one is better in terms of performance and everything?

Comment: What are you including in "and everything"?

Comment: I don't know what makes a python function better, is it only performance or are there other elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module will do ya.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've found out which function is faster using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module, you can also get more precise details of where the differences are by using the [profile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-profile) module.