# How can I compare count of performing?

Tags: python, quicksort, insertion-sort

```
import random
import time

def insertion_Sort(A):

    if len(A) == 1 :
        return A
    else :
        S = [A[0]]
        for i in range(1,len(A)):
            j = i-1
            while j >= 0:
                if A[i] > S[j]:
                    S.insert((j+1),A[i])
                    break
                else :
                    j = j-1
            if j==-1:
                    S.insert(0,A[i])
        return S




def quick_Sort(A):

    if not A:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = random.randint(0, len(A) - 1)
        pivot_index = A[pivot]
        L = quick_Sort([l for i,l in enumerate(A)
                           if l <= pivot_index and i != pivot])
        R = quick_Sort([r for r in A if r > pivot_index])
        return L + [pivot_index] + R





RN = [random.randrange(0,10000) for k in range(100)]
```

This is the code about quick_sort and insertion_sort.

I want to compare two things, insertion_sort(RN)'s count of performing and quick_sort(RN)'s count of performing.

How can I compare these things?

Comment: Use `timeit` for speed compraisons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare python functions in terms of performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956834/how-do-i-compare-python-functions-in-terms-of-performance)

Answer (score 0):

There is a python module called `timeit` which is exactly what you are looking for. You can use it as follows:

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit('insertion_Sort(params)','from __main__ import insertion_Sort',number=100))
print(timeit('quick_Sort(params)','from __main__ import quick_Sort',number=100))
```

And you replace `params` with the value of your parameter `A` and `number=100` with the number of times you want it to be tested.

Comment: Please read the comments under the question before writing an answer